# How to write Seam Tests with NonFacesRequest?

Tags: java, testing, jsf-1.2, acceptance-testing, seam2

i want to write a little test:

i have an external server calling my url:
  `domain.com/pages/test/postback.html?user_id=5`
when the url is called, the Controller method test()  should be called (defined in the page.xml)

my problem is: how can i test, that the id is filled with the correct values?
i have written a test with `NonFacesRequest`
but at the end, the value is always null

my Controller:

```
@Name(PostbackController.COMPONENT_NAME)
@AutoCreate
public class PostbackController {
    public static final String COMPONENT_NAME = "postbackController";

    @RequestParameter("user_id")
    private String userId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }



    public void test(){
        // do something
    }

}
```

my Test

```
public class PostbackTest extends SeamTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{

        new NonFacesRequest("/pages/test/postback.html?user_id=5"){

                @Override
                protected void renderResponse() throws Exception {

                PostbackController postbackController = (PostbackController) getInstance(PostbackController.class);
                    Assert.assertEquals(postbackController.getUserId(),"5");
                }
            }.run();

}
```

the postback.page.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages http://jboss.com/products/seam/pages-2.2.xsd"
    view-id="/pages/test/postback.xhtml" login-required="false">

    <action execute="#{postbackController.test}" />


<param name="user_id" />


</page>
```

the xhtml is a blank page.

Hopefully someone know how to solve the problem....